# Not able to login with mesibo chat SDK

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swift3, mesibo

I'm trying to implement chat using Xcode Framework i have download sample app for iOS. I'm not able to login the username and password which i have created in server. I'm using Swift for mesibo chat their i have created user's but I'm not able login.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem, will increase your chances of getting good answers.

Answer (score 0):

Mesibo says :"Demo app uses AccountKit which is deprecated, how to replace it?
Mesibo has no dependencies on AccountKit. The AccountKit is only used as a method in the demo apps. You can use whatever authentication method as you prefer, for example, sending OTP using SMS providers. Since the complete demo app source code is available on GitHub, you can remove AccountKit and replace it with your own screens."